# How to send some data from Windows to browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

How can I send some data like a number from an application ran in my Windows to browser(Chrome) Window Object?

I am a web developer and I don't know anything about another languages like C, C++, C#, Python and etc.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do... What is this application sending to the browser exactly?

Comment: We need more information to understand what you are attempting to do.  Right now as I read it I think you are trying to do browser automation from a desktop application.

Comment: You can use https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ to grab a value from your Windows application and put it into a form on your Web page. If that's really what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to manipulate the browser from a native windows app have a look at either [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) or the [Chromium command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)